# Trying to run a springboot war file with rest controller on tomcat 9 externally

Tags: rest, spring-boot, tomcat

I have been trying to deploy springboot apps. I tried one and could deploy the springboot with rest controller to embedded tomcat successfully. Now I am trying one more where I want to package it as a web app project and deploy to tomcat. I am able to deploy it but it doesn't resolve properly to rest controller paths and gives http 404 error. I am doing this with gradle build.

contextpath property didn't work.

My application starts up on http://localhost:8080/projectName/Welcome.jsp . I need to give this externally. It tries to move to http:localhost:8080/students on click of my link in jsp.

This gives the error - Type Status Report

Message /students

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

my gradle file :

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you 
  started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the 
 Gradle
 * user guide available at 
   https://docs.gradle.org/4.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
*/

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'war'
 apply plugin: 'java-library'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.5'
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle- 
     plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")

    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
 }

   apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
     targetCompatibility = 1.8

   bootWar{
         mainClassName = 'org.sjsu.eds.student.main.StudentMain'
     }



    dependencies {
      // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found 
  on their compile classpath.
   api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

   // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers 
      on their own compile classpath.
      implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

   // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'



    def tomcatVersion = '9.0.8'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
       "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:9.0.0.M6",
       "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}" 
       /*reference - https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat- 
      plugin/blob/master/README.md*/

 compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
  testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

compile ("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7")
compile ("org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.1.6.RELEASE")
}

  tomcat {
  httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
   ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
  }
```

My spring main file

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class StudentMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
     return application.sources(StudentMain .class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SpringApplication.run(StudentMain.class, args);
}

}
```

My rest controller simple

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/students")
public class StudentController {

private StudentServiceImplWithoutDB studentService;

@Autowired
public StudentController(StudentServiceImplWithoutDB studentService) {
    this.studentService = studentService;
}


@GetMapping
public List<StudentVO> getAll(){

    List<StudentVO> studentVO= studentService.getAllStudents();
    return studentVO;

}
}
```

Do I need to set any path or properties for war? Almost the same application worked like a charm with embedded tomcat for simple java application

Comment: I think you need to remove embedded tomcat from dependencies like compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}

Comment: It doesn't work. It still has the context 404 issue

Comment: you have to do something like that Disable the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot
Change the package type to WAR
Extend SpringBootServletInitializer in main application class
Upload the WAR file to Tomcat webapps directory

Answer (score 0):

First you have to provide tomcat as provideRunTime in gradle after that change package type as war , and then extends SpringBootServletInitializer in main class , upload war file to tomcat web folder

According to these steps

First add in gradle

```
providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
```

Change package type

```
apply plugin: "war"
```

Extends SpringBootServletInitializer class in main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Build war

```
gradle war
```